# Batch deletion of smaller files from group of files via unix command line

Tags: command-line, unix, shell, batch, shell-script

I have a large number (more than 400) of directories full of photos. What I want to do is to keep the larger sizes of these photos. Each directory has 31 to 66 files in it.

Each directory has thumbnails, and larger versions, plus a file called `example.jpg`

I dispatched the example.jpg file easily with:

```
rm */example.jpg
```

I initially thought that it would be easy to delete the thumbnails, but the problem is they are not consistently named. The typical pattern was `photo1.jpg` and `photo1s.jpg`. I did `rm */photo*s.jpg` but it ended up some of the files named `photoXs.jpg` were actually larger and not smaller. Argh.

So what I want to do is scan each directory for filesize and delete (or move) the thumbnails. I initially thought I'd just `ls -R` every file and extract the size of each file and save those under a threshold. The problem? In one directory the large will be 1.1 MB and the thumb is 200k. In another the large is 200k and the small 30k.

Even worse, the files really are mostly named `photo1.jpg` - so simply putting them all in the same folder, sorting by size, and deleting in groups would not work without renaming already, and if it's possible I'd prefer to keep them in their folders.

I was almost resolved to just doing this all manually, but then thought I'd ask here.

How would you do this task?

Comment: Is there any relationship between the name of an image and it's thumbnail image or other sized images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script makes the assumption that there's a significant gap in the sizes between the groups of smallest and largest files. In particular that the smallest of the large files is at least twice as big as the largest of the small files.

Call the script "imagedirstats" and run it in a loop such as this one:

```
find /path/to/main/branch -type d | while read subdir; do (cd "$subdir" && ~/bin/imagedirstats ); done
```

in order to find and delete files in indivdual directories in tree of directories.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# from http://superuser.com/questions/135951/batch-deletion-of-smaller-files-from-group-of-files-via-unix-command-line
# by Dennis Williamson - 2010-04-29

prevn=1     # prevent division by zero
factor=4    # how close to the largest of the small files to set the threshold, 4 == one fourth of the way above
min=1000    # ignore files below this size

while read n
do
    (( ratio = n / prevn ))
    if (( ratio > 1 && n > min ))
    then
        break
    fi
    if (( n > 0 ))
    then
        prevn=$n
    fi
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.jpg" -printf "%s\n" | sort -n)
# for OS X, comment out the preceding line and uncomment this one:
# done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.jpg" | stat -f "%z" | sort -n)

# the following line would be the GNU equivalent using stat(1) instead of printf
# it's included here for reference:
# done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.jpg" | stat -c "%s" | sort -n)

(( size = (n - prevn) / factor + prevn ))

echo "Smallest of the large: $n"
echo "Largest of the small: $prevn"
echo "Ratio: $ratio"
echo "Threshold: $size"

if (( ratio < 2 ))
then
    read -p "Warning: ratio too small. Delete anyway? Only 'Yes' will proceed" reply
    if [[ $reply != "Yes" ]]
    then
        echo "Cancelled" >&2
        exit 1
    fi
fi

# uncomment the delete on the following line to actually do the deletion

find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.jpg" -size -${size}c # -delete
```

**Edit:** Moved the warning prompt so useful information would be displayed first. Fixed a missing `fi`.

**Edit 2:** Made the two `find` commands consistent. Added a commented-out variation for OS X. Added information on running the script.

Comment: Saved this as `imagedirstats:` and ran it with `~/bin/imagedirstats */*` and the result is: `-bash: /Users/artlung/bin/imagedirstats: Argument list too long` ... run with  `~/bin/imagedirstats *` and I get: 
`find: illegal option -- p
find: illegal option -- r
find: illegal option -- i
find: illegal option -- n
find: illegal option -- t
find: %s\n: No such file or directory
/Users/artlung/bin/imagedirstats: line 38: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

Comment: The script doesn't take any arguments. It's designed to be run in the current directory or inside a loop that iterates over a set of directories. Also, see where I edited the `find` command. I forgot to include a `-maxdepth` argument.

Comment: What does `find --version` give you? What Linux distribution (and version)?

Comment: The reason for the current-directory and maxdepth restrictions is to accommodate the condition you described in your question in which file size ranges overlap across directories.

Comment: This is what the outer loop might look like: `find /path/to/main/branch -type d | while read subdir; do (cd "$subdir" &&  ~/bin/imagedirstats ); done`

Comment: @artlung: I had a missing `fi`. Fixed. Try it again.

Comment: find --version gives me: "find: illegal option -- -
find: illegal option -- v
find: illegal option -- e
find: illegal option -- r
find: illegal option -- i
find: illegal option -- o
find: illegal option -- n
usage: find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] [-f path] path ... [expression]
       find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] -f path [path ...] [expression]"

Comment: @artlung: What do `uname -a` and `lsb_release -a` or `cat /etc/lsb-release` say?

Comment: @artlung: Try changing the line with the first `find` (after the `done`) to: `done < <(find | stat -f "%z" | sort -n)` for OS X. (The equivalent for GNU would be `stat -c "%s"`.)

Answer (score 4):

If there's some specific cuttoff you can find, for example all large pictures are larger than 200KB, then you can do this:

`find */*.jpg -size -200k -delete`

You might want to make a backup copy first.

Comment: This is promising. There's not a clear cutoff in size, unfortunately, but this is a nice way to narrow down a majority maybe. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If the file sizes aren't consistent, are the image dimensions?

You could use `identify`, a tool that comes with ImageMagick, to grab the image dimensions. Through some simple bash scripting, you can work with the images depending on their size.

To grab the width and height of an image with `identify`:

```
identify -format '%wx%h' filename
```

you'll get output like so:

```
[john@awesome:~]$ identify -format '%wx%h' W4.JPG
1680x1050
```

You can then use the `cut` utility to grab the numbers in your script:

```
[john@awesome:~]$ identify -format '%wx%h' W4.JPG | cut -d'x' -f1
1680
[john@awesome:~]$ identify -format '%wx%h' W4.JPG | cut -d'x' -f2
1050
```

Comment: Okay, installing imagemagick via brew (on Mac) and will take a look. this is a piece for extracting height. I think there's some consistency in the heights of the thumbnails -- not in the larger ones. Promising!

Comment: Even if they aren't exactly consistent, if all thumbnails are less than 200 pixels in height you can do `if [ $h -lt 200 ] ... `

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this on the basis of file name, try the following:

```
find -name '*.jpg' | sed -ne 's:^\(.*\)\.jpg:\1s.jpg$:p' | xargs rm
```

It will find every .jpg file, put an "s" at the end of the filename (just before the ".") and delete it.

Comment: The OP said the files are inconsistently named and some of the large files have "s".

Comment: Thanks petersohn, but DW is right. If they were named like a sane person would name them then it would be much easier to simply delete files matching the pattern and be done.